# How to update instance's property, from another instance without only a property input

Tags: python, class, instance

```
class Function:
     def __init__(self, value, secret):
         self.value = value
         self.secret = secret

     def run_sim(self):
         ins = Check(self._value)
         ins.run()


class Check:
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value

     def run(self):
         # is it possible to update Function.value here?
         # or get the value of Function.secret of the same Function instance that used to 
         # initialise this instance of class

         # without modifying the __init__ of this class
```

is it possible to update Function.value in another class without a full instance as an input.
I can do it with modifying the **init** of Check, but my teacher claim it is possible to do this without modifying the **init** of this class

Comment: Could you give a little more context - why does `Check` need so much access to the `Function` that created it? If it needs the secret too, why not pass that in?

Comment: This was modified from my homework, I afraid I cannot post the exact question

The original question is very similar to this question, my teacher claim that it is possible to update the properties of the instance in Function, by only allowing us to modify the code in Check.run()

Answer (score 0):

You can use some variant of polymorphism:

```
class Function:
    def __init__(self, value, secret):
        self.value = value
        self.secret = secret

    def run_sim(self):
        ins = Check(self._value)
        ins.run()


class Check:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def run(self, function_instance):
        function_instance.value = self.value


if __name__=='__main__':
    f = Function(1,True)
    print(f.value)
    c = Check(5)

    c.run(f)
    print(f.value)
```

Which outputs:

```
1
5
```

Is this what you're looking for?